# Linux command to retrieve the number of times a user has logged in that week

Tags: linux, authentication

I want a count of the number of times a user, say root or ubuntu has logged in that week - lastlog gives me the information but without doing some parsing, is there a straighforward command to obtain the information.

```
    lastlog | grep logged | awk '{print $1}'
```

The above for example, gives me who are the users who never logged in.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try last command:

last -F |grep user |wc -l

https://linux-commands-examples.blogspot.com/2018/12/last.html